# PLSQL check for the column value and replace it with blank

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is one column named `'Type'` and it will have multiple comma separated values.

I have to check if it contains `'Test1','Test2 Test3'` or `'Test4'` and replace it with blank. How to do it?

I tried finding those words in the column value and using the `replace` function but it doesn't clear out the comma before/after the value.

Also if I replace the comma by blank, it will get replace before and after all the values. I also want to make sure that my code consumes the least execution time which is obviously not possible if I use three different update functions for all the records one by one.

Comment: *"There is one column named 'Type' and it will have multiple comma separated values. "* Well there's the first mistake. The wages of sin are constant pfaffing around with string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only the matching words (specific values) with blank

```
SELECT REPLACE('Test1 and Test2','Test1','') "Changes" 
FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to replace the whole value with blank when matching patterns

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Test1 and Test2' LIKE '%Test1%' THEN '' END 
FROM DUAL;
```